# Pyton Regular Expressions-Find all sentences starting with a hyphen character and put them in a list

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file i want to parse through and put the questions and options into a question and options list

example text: [UPDATED THE EXAMPLE TEXT TO INCLUDE ALL THE TYPES OF VARIATIONS IN THE QUESTION TYPES AND OPTIONS]

```
- 26 yrs Man Hbsag +ve ,hbeag +ve on routine screening ..what is next ; IM
A. observe
B. HBV DNA study\
C. Interferon
D. take liver biopsy
- Trauma è skin erythema and Partiel skin loss ,ttt: surgery
A. H2o irrigation
B. Bicarb. Irrigation
C. Surgical debridment\
- Old female, obese on diet control ,polydipsia , invest. Hba1c 7.5 ,all (random,
Fasting, post prandial ) sugar are mild elevated urine ketone (+) ttt: IM
A. Insulin “ ketonuria “\
B. pioglitazone
C. Thiazolidinediones
D. fourth i forgot (not Metformin nor sulfonylurea)
- Day to day variation of this not suitable for patients under warfarin therapy: IM
A. retinols
B. Fresh fruits and vegitables
C. Meet and paultry\
D. Old cheese
```

I am new to python and especially new to regular expressions. Trying to find the regular expression that will find sentences starting with '-' and when the new line has 'A.' , slice it before the 'A.' and put the questions in the list.Note:Some questions are two lines long.

Also a regular expression to extract each set of options into a list. So end result would be:

```
question list = ['- 26 yrs Man Hbsag +ve ,hbeag +ve on routine screening ..what is next ; IM','- Old female, obese on diet control ,polydipsia , invest. Hba1c 7.5 ,all (random,Fasting, post prandial ) sugar are mild elevated urine ketone (+) ttt:IM ','etc','and so on']
```

```
options list = [['A. observe','B. HBV DNA study\','C. Interferon','D. take liver biopsy'],['A. H2o irrigation\','B. Bicarb. Irrigation','C. Surgical debridment',[['A. Something Else','B. Something Else',......,'D.  ']],[etc]]
```

Im Guessing this would be a bit complicated , but any help with the regular expression part or even a start would be great. I have a text file with 1000 such question and options repeating like that, and ideally would like to extract all questions and options.

```
import re

with open("julysmalltext.txt") as file:
    content = file.read()
    question_list = re.findall(r'', content)
    options_list = re.findall(r'', content)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

```
import re
 
with open("data.txt") as fp:
    question_list = list()
    options_list = list()
    for line in fp.readlines():
        question = re.match(r'-.*', line)
        if question:
            question_list.append(question.group(0))
        else:
            answer = re.match(r'[ABCD]\..*', line)
            if answer.group(0)[0]=='A':
                options_list.append([answer.group(0)])
            else:
                options_list[-1].append(answer.group(0))

print(question_list)
print(options_list)
```

Output:

```
['- 26 yrs Man Hbsag +ve ,hbeag +ve on routine screening ..what is next ;IM', '- Trauma è skin erythema and Partiel skin loss ,ttt: surgery']
[['A. observe', 'B. HBV DNA study', 'C. Interferon', 'D. take liver biopsy'], ['A. H2o irrigation', 'B. Bicarb. Irrigation', 'C. Surgical debridment']]
```

Another option, if you don't need nested question list:

```
import re

with open("data.txt") as file:
    content = file.read()
    question_list = re.findall(r'-.*', content)
    options_list = re.findall(r'[ABCD]\..*', content)

print(question_list)
print(options_list)
```

Output:

```
['- 26 yrs Man Hbsag +ve ,hbeag +ve on routine screening ..what is next ;IM', '- Trauma è skin erythema and Partiel skin loss ,ttt: surgery']
['A. observe', 'B. HBV DNA study', 'C. Interferon', 'D. take liver biopsy', 'A. H2o irrigation', 'B. Bicarb. Irrigation', 'C. Surgical debridment']
```

Comment: Hey thanks , the second option is close enough! I apologize , but i updated the post for questions those that are two lines long too. The first option u provided is even better the way your output looks but it errored out for me with this :* AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' * at this line * :if answer.group(0)[0]=='A': * . Its probably cause im using the entire file to parse and it has questions with two lines and also some text that does not follow the pattern. But main update that would be great is if the question has two lines. Either ways thanks a lot for answer!

Comment: The `.*` is completely superfluous, and you might as well use `if content.startswith('-')` to check for a static string.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
import re

with open("julysmalltext.txt") as file:
    content = file.read()

questions = re.findall('-.*?(?=\nA)', content)
options = re.findall('\w\..*?(?=\n)', content)

print(questions)
print(options)
```

Output:

```
['- 26 yrs Man Hbsag +ve ,hbeag +ve on routine screening ..what is next ;IM', '- Trauma è skin erythema and Partiel skin loss ,ttt: surgery']
['A. observe', 'B. HBV DNA study', 'C. Interferon', 'D. take liver biopsy', 'A. H2o irrigation\\', 'B. Bicarb. Irrigation']
```

---

Breaking it down:

This part: `'-'` means that the string must begin with `'-'`

This part: `'.*?'` means to extract everything in between, but not greedy.

This part: `'(?=\nA)'` means that there must be a newline and an `'A'` right in front of the string.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much, this helps me solve 80% of it , i updated the post to include the entire sample text so there are questions with two lines and some more variations in the options , example options that have only uptil 'C.' options . Mainly, it would be great if the question finding regular expression takes into account question text that are two lines long too. Thanks for your answer anyways , the explanation given helps a lot to understand too! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this example.

```
import json

text = '''
- 26 yrs Man Hbsag +ve ,hbeag +ve on routine screening ..what is next ;IM
A. observe
B. HBV DNA study
C. Interferon
D. take liver biopsy
- Trauma è skin erythema and Partiel skin loss ,ttt: surgery
A. H2o irrigation\
B. Bicarb. Irrigation
C. Surgical debridment
'''

questions = {}
letters = ['A','B','C','D','E',]
text = text.split('\n')
text[:]          = [x for x in text if x]
question = ''
for line in text:
    if line[0] == '-':
        question = line[2:]
        questions[question] = {}
    elif line[0] in letters:
        line = line.split('.',1)
        for i in range(len(line)):
            line[i] = line[i].strip()
        questions[question][line[0]] = line[1]


print(json.dumps(questions,indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

The output will be very organized:

```
{
  "26 yrs Man Hbsag +ve ,hbeag +ve on routine screening ..what is next ;IM": {
    "A": "observe",
    "B": "HBV DNA study",
    "C": "Interferon",
    "D": "take liver biopsy"
  },
  "Trauma è skin erythema and Partiel skin loss ,ttt: surgery": {
    "A": "H2o irrigationB. Bicarb. Irrigation",
    "C": "Surgical debridment"
  }
}
```